# Aparecer div ao clicar sobre a imagem

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Preciso fazer um sistema de seleção, em que o usuário terá sempre 3 opções dependendo do que ele escolher.
Preciso que ao clicar na imagem1 apareça a div1 se clicar na imagem2 apareça a div3.
Mas quero que ao clicar isso apareça de forma gradativa, como se fosse um paralax.

Comment: Cara poste o código que vc já tem até então para receber maior ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para fazer uma div aparecer ou desaparecer você deve mudar a propriedade "display" dela:

```
  <div style="display: none" > texto 1 </div> /* "none" quer dizer que ele está invisivel*/
  <div style="display: block" > texto 1 </div> /* "block" está visivel*/
```

Você pode fazer um CSS para isso, e muda-lo com funções javascript;